# Contain an image inside a smaller parent div without resizing the image

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do we contain an image inside a smaller parent div (Smaller than the size of the image) using html and css (jquery solution is also ok). The image should not resize or crop and the visibility of image should restrict to that of the parent div. Image may be itself inside div2 (not necessarily).

[image]

As in the picture the image is larger than that of div1 and the visibility of the image is restricted to the parent div (div1). Another div (div3) is placed just below div1 irrespective to the size of the image.

Is there are any concerns of the focal point of the image is shown as in

```
background-position: bottom;
```

NB: In the given image the bottom part of the flower pot is shown solely for illustration purpose in real that part will be hidden outside the div1.

Answer (score 0):

Create a div container around the image, set it for a height, and make it overflow hidden:

```css
.image-container {
overflow: hidden;
height: 250px;
border: 1px solid red;
}

img {
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
<img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/4/3939/15487040296_90539d40f9_b.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: I think while using this code the image resizes to the parent div :  [see the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LalasMuathasim/j59eh582/)

Comment: I think we need to set width: auto; instead 100% .. Thank you for the idea

Comment: sure set the width to a static number and then it won't resize.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, background images will automatically get cropped when they go beyond the boundaries of their element.

So you can set the image as a `background-image` of your `div`. If your image is too big that it goes beyond the `div` and gets cropped, you can use the `background-size` property, and it has two very useful values: `contain` and `cover`.

```
div {
    background-image: url("path/to/image.jpg");
    background-size: contain; /* or cover */
}
```

With `background-size: contain`, the background image will get resized until it is fully contained inside your `div`. On the other hand, `background-size: cover` will make sure that your `div` is fully covered by the image.

I hope I understood your question properly.